# How to add collision physics in Unity Mapbox World Scale?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, collision-detection

In World Scale AR, I want to move to an object I placed using SpawnOnMap. When I touch that object, I want that object to be erased. I made the Player have a script called PlayerController. I made a tag for the object so that when it touches, it should destroy or set it active. When I walk towards the object, nothing happens. I've tried OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter already. Is there some kind of method I'm missing that Mapbox provides?

```
public class PelletCollector : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int count = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Pellet")
        {

            count++;
            Debug.Log("Collected Pellets: " + count);

            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            //Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u add a collider to your Object ?

Comment: @QusaiAzzam of course!

Comment: where is the Touch Event? there is no touch event! , the previous function triggers when two objects inside the scene collides

Comment: @QusaiAzzam Sorry I should have made it clearer by what I meant by touch. I meant the Player colliding with the object in a 3D environment, not when the Player touch the object on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for Clarification, the player should have a collider in order to trigger the OnCollisionEnter event!

Comment: The player and object both have a sphere collider with a OnTrigger and a Rigidbody. The object has a prefab, which is duplicated multiple times but placed in different latitude and longitude.